# Eclipse Started Randomly Printing Hundreds of Blank/Empty Lines to Console

Tags: java, eclipse, console

For some odd reason  Eclipse started printing hundreds of empty lines to console randomly. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I recently added YourKit plugin. I believe this was the only modification I made to Eclipse since this started happening.

I've removed virtually all System.out.println() statements from my program, to see if this has anything to do with it, but the problem still persists. Eclipse still prints hundreds of empty lines to console.

What might be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It is an Eclipse bug. It maybe because of console output limit.

> Sometimes it can be characters that are not visible.
> See if you can copy those blank lines and paste it in some text editors to check for characters.

Check for console output limit in your settings.
`Windows->Preferences->Run/Debug->Console`. And uncheck `limit console output`.

Comment: @viki thanks. You are correct that when I copy paste the 'empty' lines into a text editor they are full with text - actually very wide text. I did uncheck the limit console output field as you suggested and restarted Eclipse but the problem still persists. Any additional insight wold be much appreciated!

Comment: @viki Also, I should add that the text that appears in text editor are normal characters like numbers and text. I didn't notice any special chars that might prevent them from being displayed. The number of chars on each line is VERY long. This might be part of the problem. Not sure though.